# Google Cloud Storage event trigger causes Too many overlapping notifications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function from Cloud Shell and a review of the logs shows the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST 
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/notificationConfigs? 
prettyPrint=false: Too many overlapping notifications. The maximum is 10.
```

The error is thrown when this code is triggered in response to a Cloud Storage event, specifically  Finalize/Create of a new object.

```
def notifier(event, context):    
    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {} to {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp, context.resource["name"]))

    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("my-bucket")
    notification = bucket.notification(topic_name="my-bucket-upload")
    notification.create()
    print(f"Successfully created notification with ID {notification.notification_id} for {bucket_name}")
```

I could find no reference to this error and I don't know what to try next.  What could be causing this error message?

Comment: Is the deployment complete? Can you also share the complete deploy command you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotfix:
Remove `notification.create()` from that code.